# Empty variables in termux' bash

Tags: bash, termux

I want to perform a test: if a certain variable exists, is non-empty, and its value matches an existing directory, then "exists" should be outputted.

I did the following:

```
$ echo $var

$ if [ -d $var ]; then echo "exists"; fi
exists
```

I got "exist", although I did not assign any value to `$var`. Why did this happen, and how do I test this properly?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If @WillW answered your question, please mark it as accepted! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to wrap $var in quotes.

`if [ -d "$var" ]; then echo "exists"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

> [ -d FILE ]   True if FILE exists and is a directory

You probably want to use one of these tests instead:

> [ -z STRING ] True of the length if "STRING" is zero.
>
> [ -n STRING ] or [ STRING ]   True if the length of "STRING" is non-zero.

From https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

> how do I test this properly?
>   if a certain variable exists, is non-empty

This question is discussed in detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash here.

> its value matches an existing directory

This code [[ "${F1AR[@]}" =~ "${NAME##*/}" ]] checks if values match existing directories.  From https://github.com/BuildAPKs/buildAPKs/blob/master/scripts/bash/build/build.github.bash#L59